# NodeJS : Waiting 5 seconds between URL requests is not working

Tags: node.js, request, settimeout

I am trying to crawl a list of URLS on my website. I want to wait five seconds between URL requests but the problem is that no matter how I bury my setTImeout function into the script it does not wait the way that I want it to.

```
var urlArray=["http://domain.com/page1.php", "http://domain.com/page2.php", ... ];
var request = require('request');
function logStatus(url){ 
    request(url, function (err, res, body){
        console.log(res.statusCode); 
    });
    return 1;
} 
function doSetTimeout(getURL){
    timer = setTimeout(logStatus(getURL), 5000);
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
urlArray.forEach(function(entry) {
    doSetTimeout(entry); 
    //setTimeout(logStatus(entry), 5000)
});
```

**Working Edit:**

```
var request = require('request');
function logStatus(url){ 
    return 1;
} 
var waitInSeconds=5;
var waitInMilliSeconds=waitInSeconds*1000; 
console.log('This scan will take '+((urlArray.length * waitInSeconds)/60)+' minutes');
for(i=0; i<=1000;i++){ 
    if(!urlArray[i]) { //if url number i is not in array
        break;
    };
    (function(i){
        setTimeout(function(){
            request(urlArray[i], function (err, res, body){
                console.log(res.statusCode);
                if(i/10 % 1 === 0 ){ //if we have completed 10 more requests, let the user no how much time is remaining.
                    console.log(((urlArray.length * waitInSeconds)/60)+' minutes remaining.');
                } 
            }); 
        }, waitInMilliSeconds * i);
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: This construct `setTimeout(logStatus(getURL), 5000);` calls `logStatus(getURL)` immediately.  It doesn't wait for the timeout.  You need to pass a function reference to `setTimeout()` that can be called later.  `fn()` is called immediately.  `fn` is a function reference that can be called later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var urlArray=["http://domain.com/page1.php", "http://domain.com/page2.php", ... ];
var request = require('request');

function processUrls(urls) {
  var url = urls.shift();
  logStatus(url, function() {
    if(urls.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(processUrls.bind(this, urls));
    }
  });
}

function logStatus(url, done){ 
  request(url, function (err, res, body){
    console.log(res.statusCode); 
    done();
  });
} 

processUrls(urlArray);
```

Comment: Thanks Timothy, I actually worked found an alternative solution since posting this. Though yours is cleaner and may work, this project isn't critical enough to change my working solution for a cleaner one. 

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: The best answers contain a description of what was wrong in the original question and what you're changing in your answer and why that fixes it.  Answers like this leave the reader to try to figure out what you changed and why which are not as informative or useful as it could be.